# Python: Convert dataframe into a list with string items inside list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have code that reads in an Excel table (image below):

```
# Read in zipcode input file

us_zips = pd.read_excel("Zipcode.xls")
us_zips
```

[image]

I use the following code to convert the dataframe zip codes into a list:

```
us_zips = list(us_zips.values.flatten())
```

When I print us_zips it looks like this:

[10601, 60047, 50301, 10606]

...but I want it to look like this ["10601", "60047", "50301", "10606"]

How can I do that?  *Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can just cast the column dtype using [`astype(str)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) and then convert to list using `.values.tolist()`, this returns a numpy array using [`.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) which has a member function to convert this to a list:

```
In [321]:
us_zips['zipcode'].astype(str).values.tolist()

Out[321]:
['10601', '60047', '50301', '10606']
```

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me without `.values()`:

```
list = df[col_name].astype(str).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating your list you can simply do the following to convert all your list elements to strings:

```
us_zips = [str(i) for i in us_zips]
```

**Complete code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["x"] = [10601, 60047, 50301, 10606]
us_zips = list(df["x"].values.flatten())
print(us_zips)
us_zips = [str(i) for i in us_zips]
print(us_zips)
```

**Results:**

```
[10601, 60047, 50301, 10606]
['10601', '60047', '50301', '10606']
```