# reading large string and split each word taking too much time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am reading a dataframe column having comments. The data is taking forever to read using the code below. Is there a way to make this faster ?

```
for val in df.Description:
    val = str(val)
    tokens = val.split()  
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower()  
        for words in tokens:
            comment = comment + words + ''
```

df.Description is a column of comments (basically email text)

Comment: Can you make it more clear, such as give some examples to show what the `val` in `df.Description` looks like, and what the `comment` is.

Comment: `comment = comment + words + ''` is a very inefficient way to build up a string. Build up a list of strings then `''.join()` it at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Assuming df.Description is your column, this might be helpful:

```
arr_string = df.Description.astype(str).values.tolist()
for val in arr_string:
    for words in val:
            comment = ''.join([comment, words])
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768231/6013016).

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'