# Python/Pandas: How do I replace specific values of a Pandas Data Frame based on individual id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, replace

I have a long Pandas dataset that contains a column called `'id'` and another column called `'species'`, among other columns. I have to perform a change on the `'species'` column, based on specific values of the `'id'` column.

For example, if the `'id'` is `'5555555'` (as a string), then I want that the `'species'` value change its current value `'dove'` (also a string) to `'hummingbird'`.  So far I have been using the method:

`df.loc[df["id"] == '5555555', "species"] = 'hummingbird'`

Here is short sample data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
        
#Starting dataset
d = {'id': ['11111111', '22222222', '33333333', '44444444', '55555555', '66666666', '77777777', '88888888'], 'species': ['dove', 'dove', 'dove', 'hummingbird', 'hummingbird', 'dove', 'hummingbird', 'dove']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    
    id          species
0   11111111    dove
1   22222222    dove        #wants to replace
2   33333333    dove        #wants to replace
3   44444444    hummingbird
4   55555555    hummingbird
5   66666666    dove
6   77777777    hummingbird
7   88888888    dove        #wants to replace        
     
#Expected outcome
d = {'id': ['11111111', '22222222', '33333333', '44444444', '55555555', '66666666', '77777777', '88888888'], 'species': ['dove', 'hummingbird', 'hummingbird', 'hummingbird', 'hummingbird', 'dove', 'hummingbird', 'hummingbird']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    
    id          species
0   11111111    dove
1   22222222    hummingbird #replaced
2   33333333    hummingbird #replaced
3   44444444    hummingbird
4   55555555    hummingbird
5   66666666    dove
6   77777777    hummingbird
7   88888888    hummingbird #replaced
```

This is ok for a small number of lines, but I have to do this to about 1000 lines with individual `'id'` each, so I thought that maybe a loop that I could feed it the list of `'id'`, but I honestly do not know how to even start.

Thanks in advance!!

and thanks to Scott Boston for pointing me out in the right direction to ask better questions!

Comment: kindly add sample dataset with expected output

Comment: Will do, thank you for the advice!

Comment: Why does 2222 and 3333 change but not 1111?

Comment: @ScottBoston because those are the ones that I might want to change. The assumption is that those specific```'id'```were named incorrectly on my dataset, therefore I want to change them, only that in real life I have about 1000 of them, so I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way than having to copy and paste the method that I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Okay... for this question it is best if you create a small toy dataset and a list of id's you want to change and the values you want to change.  You question here as stated is pretty broad hence you have no current answers.   I suspect what you are trying to accomplish is pretty easy just that we are not sure what your inputs nor your expected output is.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to help use help you.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction to ask better questions! I'm sure I'll get better with time, but I hope this new version of my question can clarify what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`

```
humming_ids = [44444444, 5555555, 88888888]
df.loc[df.id.isin(humming_ids), "species"] = 'hummingbird'
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vishnudev! This worked great. I also want to mention that I combined your answer with an answer from another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768196/python-convert-dataframe-into-a-list-with-string-items-inside-list) since I also needed to extract the id from an excel sheet and then convert them into a python list to use your answer.  You have no idea how much this will help me!